# Linear regression - equation on the plot - Python

Tags: python, math, plot, linear-regression

Hey I want to do linear regression and create a plot on which will be also equation of my model. I have following code:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

X = np.array((1,2, 3, 4))
Y = np.array((3, 1, 4, 5))

X = X.reshape((-1, 1))
model = LinearRegression().fit(X, Y)


plt.scatter(X, Y, color='g')
plt.plot(X, model.predict(X),color='k')

print(model.coef_[0], model.intercept_)
```

How to write equation on my plot automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Text in Matplotlib Plots](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/text/text_intro.html#:%7E:text=Basic%20text%20commands,-The%20following%20commands&text=Add%20an%20annotation%2C%20with%20an,arbitrary%20location%20of%20the%20Axes%20.&text=Add%20a%20label%20to%20the%20Axes%20%27s%20x%2Daxis.&text=Add%20a%20label%20to%20the%20Axes%20%27s%20y%2Daxis.&text=Add%20a%20title%20to%20the%20Axes%20.)

> Matplotlib has extensive text support, including support for mathematical expressions, truetype support for raster and vector outputs, newline separated text with arbitrary rotations, and unicode support.

From the [official documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/text/text_intro.html#:%7E:text=Basic%20text%20commands,-The%20following%20commands&text=Add%20an%20annotation%2C%20with%20an,arbitrary%20location%20of%20the%20Axes%20.&text=Add%20a%20label%20to%20the%20Axes%20%27s%20x%2Daxis.&text=Add%20a%20label%20to%20the%20Axes%20%27s%20y%2Daxis.&text=Add%20a%20title%20to%20the%20Axes%20.) the following commands are used to create text in the pyplot interface and the object-oriented API:

| pyplot API | OO API | description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| text | text | Add text at an arbitrary location of the Axes. |
| annotate | annotate | Add an annotation, with an optional arrow, at an arbitrary location of the Axes. |
| xlabel | set_xlabel | Add a label to the Axes's x-axis. |
| ylabel | set_ylabel | Add a label to the Axes's y-axis. |
| title | set_title | Add a title to the Axes. |
| figtext | text | Add text at an arbitrary location of the Figure. |
| suptitle | suptitle | Add a title to the Figure. |

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = np.array((1,2, 3, 4))
Y = np.array((3, 1, 4, 5))

X = X.reshape((-1, 1))
model = LinearRegression().fit(X, Y)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot()
plt.scatter(X, Y, color='g')
plt.plot(X, model.predict(X),color='k')
ax.text(1, 4, r'LR equation: $Y = a + bX$', fontsize=10)

print(model.coef_[0], model.intercept_)
```

**Plot:**

[image]

Comment: The case is that I want to print `Y = model.coef_[0] x + model.intercept_` instead of `Y = a + bX` and I want to do it automatically and dont write it by hand

Comment: You could try something like `ax.text(1, 4, f'$Y = {model.coef_[0]} * x + {model.intercept_}$', fontsize=10)`. Round `ax.text(1, 4, f'$Y = {round(model.coef_[0], 2)} * x + {model.intercept_}$', fontsize=10)`